# Getting bad_weak_ptr when I use shared_from_this in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

I am new to C++ and trying to understand how to correctly use shared_from_this in my situation.

I have a client connection class and server connection class both inherit from Base connection class. Base class method handles all messages it received(the node could be either client or server).

And I have a ConnMgr class responsible for starting and handling new connections. When the client node initiates a connection I am allocating a ClientConn shared_ptr object and when server receives the connection I am creating a ServerConn shared_ptr object and assigning it to tcp_conn_ in ConnMgr class, which is a map of socket_addr and BaseConn shared_ptr.

Once the connection is established, for processing the message I need to generate an instance of "this" shared_ptr. When I try to do that using shared_from_this(), its throwing bad_weak_ptr exception. 
I understand:

- Base shared_ptr and Derived shared_ptr are NOT covariant.
- Also, enable_shared_from_this expects to get shared_ptr when shared_from_this() is called.

In my situation shared_ptr was created as either ClientConn or ServerConn which I don't have any idea in the base class method. I tried to cast it too, but it did not help. So, how can I fix this?

**Snippet of backtrace:**

__gnu_cxx3__712_Lock_policyE2EE15_M_add_ref_lockEv
__gnu_cxx3__712_Lock_policyE2EEC1ERKNS_12__weak_countILS3_2EEE
__gnu_cxx3__712_Lock_policyE2EEC2IS1_EERKNS_10__weak_ptrIT_LS4_2EEE

```
class BaseConn : public std::enable_shared_from_this<BaseConn>
{
    void process_received_message()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<BaseConn> shared_this = shared_from_this();
    }
}

class ClientConn : public BaseConn
{
}

class ServerConn : public BaseConn
{
}

class ConnMgr
{
private:
    //there can be more than one connections. Hence using map.
    typedef std:map<socket_addr, std::shared_ptr<BaseConn>> tcp_conn_t;
    tcp_conn_t tcp_conn_;

public:
    void start_connection()
    {
        tcp_conn_[0] = std::make_shared<ClientConn>();
    }

    void handle_new_connection()
    {
        tcp_conn_[0] = std::make_shared<ServerConn>();
    }        
}
```

I also tried doing this, its not helping either:

```
class BaseConn
{
public:
    void process_received_message()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<BaseConn> shared_this = get_shared_ptr();
    }

    virtual std::shared_ptr<BaseConn> get_shared_ptr() = 0;
}

class ClientConn : public std::enable_shared_from_this<ClientConn>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseConn> get_shared_ptr()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<BaseConn>(shared_from_this());
    }
}

class ServerConn : public std::enable_shared_from_this<ServerConn>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseConn> get_shared_ptr()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<BaseConn>(shared_from_this());
    }
}

class ConnMgr
{
private:
    //there can be more than one connections. Hence using map.
    typedef std:map<socket_addr, std::shared_ptr<BaseConn>> tcp_conn_t;
    tcp_conn_t tcp_conn_;

public:
    void start_connection()
    {
        tcp_conn_[0] = std::make_shared<ClientConn>();
    }

    void handle_new_connection()
    {
        tcp_conn_[0] = std::make_shared<ServerConn>();
    }        
}
```

Comment: what does the debugger say about the state of `weak_ptr` member of your connection objects? Is it initialized after `make_shared` calls? If so, at what point does it go stale?

Comment: You cannot call shared_from_this if no other shared pointer to this object exists. In particular, calling it from a constructor will most of the time result in this error.

Comment: @n.m. it appears he's not calling it from the constructor though, but rather from the map of `shared_ptr`s

Comment: @Ap31 Calling from a constructor is just an example.

Comment: Thanks nm and Ap31.
I understand we cannot call shared_from_this if no shared pointer for the object exists. That's the reason I am asking how to fix in these cases?

Comment: I edited current question and described another approach I took to address this issue. But unfortunately that is not helping either. Is there any way around it?

Comment: It is working now. Please ignore my question. I actually had one more instance of the class and it was a raw pointer.